# EditTexts and Buttons will be displayed in Gingerbread style when the app is set to full screen

Tags: android, android-theme

Good day mates. I have a problem with my Android application. When the title bar is present in my app, the `Button` and `EditText` are displayed using the Android 4.4 theme. But when I set my application to fullscreen in `AndroidManifest.xml`, they are displayed in the Gingerbread theme. Please help because I really don't know why the theme has changed.

Comment: Please post your `AndroidManifest.xml` so I can answer specific to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you use a theme that inherits from the old pre 4.0 theme, such as `Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`. If you want a full screen activity that doesn't use Gingerbread components, you will need to use a custom theme.

I'd strongly suggest using an `AppCompatActivity` and making the theme inherit from `Theme.AppCompat`, like so:

```
<style name="Theme.Custom.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

This will give you a full screen activity that still uses the `AppCompat` theme and doesn't look out of place.